# Is there a way to combine on events in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following and more ..

```
        ck.on('change', function () {
            update();
        });

        ck.on('mode', function () {
            update();
        });
```

Is there a way I can combine these in jQuery/Javascript ?

Answer (score 6):

```
 ck.on('change mode', function () {
            update();
        });
```

That's it.

Comment: Even easier, `ck.on('change mode',update)` unless update relies on it's own `this`

Comment: @KevinB yes conditions apply